# Rails 5 - PostgreSQL removing migration where column and index has already been destroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have already destroyed a scaffold "Location" and its table but I forgot to rollback/remove a migrated column "slug and its index" before destroying the "Location" table . How can I remove the migration for slug and index.

Migrated slug column

```
class AddSlugToLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :locations, :slug, :string
    add_index :locations, :slug
  end
end
```

Your help will be really appreciated, heroku won't deploy because of this issue

I have tried `ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration.where(version=20180412191332).delete_all` but no luck

Also tried `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20180412191332` but giving error: No indexes found on locations with the options provided.

Comment: How did you remove Location? with another migration?

Comment: @AnaMaríaMartínezGómez, I used `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=<version for location>` and used `rail destroy scaffold Location`

Comment: When the table is already deleted then the index was removed too. Or do I miss something?

Comment: @spickermann, yes in rails 5 when the "Location" table was destroyed it automatically removed the index. However, running rake db:migrate in heroku production throws error because it tries to migrate `AddSlugToLocations`. where the slug and index do not exist Heroku error: `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "locations" does not exist. 
: ALTER TABLE "locations" ADD "slug" character varying`

Comment: Why don't you just delete the `AddSlugToLocations` migration?

Comment: @spickermann, Ok that sounds straight forward but I'm thinking deleting the `AddSlugToLocations` file without a complete rollback will break the app

Comment: rails d migration AddSlugToLocations locations:string, try this

Comment: @spickermann, it didn't work after manually deleting because migration version for slg/index is still on the Schema. Error is:  `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "locations" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "locations" ADD "slug" character varying`

Comment: As far as I understand the whole `locations` table doesn't exist in production and therefore the index does not exist either. How can it break the app when you delete the migration that does nothing than altering an (un-existing) table?

Comment: @spickermann, I have tried again and this works perfectly. Successfully deployed in production. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

If you're having trouble deleting the migration from your, schema, you could try to do it in the SQL console :

```
USE mytable/dev;
DELETE FROM schema_migrations WHERE version = '20180412191332';
```

Comment: I tried above in the console, DELETE FROM schema_migrations WHERE version = '20180412191332'; nothing happened...cursor is blinking in next row requesting further input

Answer (score 5):

You manually deleted a table from your application's database. Now running migrations raises an error because one of the migrations is trying to alter the table that doesn't exist anymore.

Just delete the failing migration from your codebase and redeploy your application.

From your question, I assume that the migration with the number `20180412191332` causes the issue. Find that migration file in `db/migrate/20180412191332_...rb`, delete it and redeploy to Heroku.

Answer (score 3):

as @spickermann noted, just delete the migration

`git rm path/to/offending/migration
git commit -m "removed unneeded migration"`

(assuming you're using commit because heroku likes deploying with git push...)

it won't be in the `schema_migrations` table if it's failed to run every time so you don't need to delete it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Scaffold generates other files in addition to migration. But this comment focus on the migration part.

An already migrated migration has

1. `db/migrate/<migrationfile>.rb`
2. updated `db/schema.rb`
3. new table/dropped table/change(s) in the table(s)
4. new record in `schema_migrations`

So, to successfully revert you have to undo all 4. We can see that the changes are in two places - source code and database.

Heroku and your local development environment will have the same code base but two separate databases.

I will check

- `schema.rb` is free of what you don't want
- `heroku rails db:migrate:status`
- rollback if necessary via rake task
- if rake task gives any error, try to delete `schema_migrations` version using psql